# Observable with inner observables

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have been working with Observables a bit, but can't figure out how to do the following:

1. I have an observable that emits an array of IDs.
2. I then want to retrieve these IDs, again using Observables.
3. Finally I want to put everything together in an Observable that
   emits an array of the retrieved items.

I could put my code attempts here, but I don't think it would help a lot.
I'm using RxJS 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for that [flattening operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) for that (like [mergeMap](http://rxmarbles.com/#mergeMap) or [concatMap](http://rxmarbles.com/#concatMap) depending on requirements). For example:

```js
const { Observable, combineLatest, of, from } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { mergeMap, toArray, map } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const transform = id => of(`${id}-transformed`);

of(ids).pipe(
  mergeMap(ids => ids),
  mergeMap(id => transform(id)),
  toArray()
).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got to one mergeMap myself, then got lost :)